# Best way pass array as query params for pg PoolClient with postgres using typescript

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql

I am fetching some data from the postgres database with typescript using pg PoolClient, currently, I am fetching using the below way please let me know if there is any better way to achieve the same

```
const SPECIAL_LIST = [
    "ABC",
    "XYZ",
    "PQR",
    "LMN",
    "EFG",
    "IJK",
  ];
var params = SPECIAL_LIST.reduce(function (a, b, idx) {
    if (idx === 0) return '$' + (idx + 2);
    else return a + ', $' + (idx + 2);
  }, '');
const sql = "Select sg.code,sg.dep,sg.vo,sg.arr from table1 sg where sg.is_omitted is false and v_code = $1 and sg.r_code not in (" +params+ ") order by sg.est_datetime asc"
  const values = [vesselCode].concat(SPECIAL_LIST);
  const client = await pool.connect();
  await client
    .query(sql, values)
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.rows;
      console.log(res.rowCount)
      data.forEach((row) => {
        // function logic
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error(e))
    .then(() => client.release());
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using ANY below is the solution

```
const sql =
    `SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7
    FROM ${TABLE_NAME}
    WHERE omitted IS FALSE
    AND v1 = $1
    AND NOT rcode = ANY ($2)
    ORDER BY datetime_dt ASC`;
  const values = [vCode, SPECIAL_SITES];

  const client = await pool.connect();
  await client
    .query({ text: sql, values: values })
    .then((res) => {
      res.rows.forEach((row) => {
        //......
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error(e))
    .then(() => client.release());
```